# How to use tfm font with "LAE" encoding with xelatex & lualatex

Tags: xetex, luatex, font-encodings

I have this example of writing arabic with tfm font which  work fine with `pdflatex`, the font is provided from `arabi` package.

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/language/arabic/arabi

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE]{fontenc}

\TeXXeTstate=1 % to anable right to left writing 

\begin{document}

\fontencoding{LAE}\fontfamily{aealyermook} \selectfont 

\beginR
نص عربي
123 

\end{document}
```

My hope is writing with this font in `xelatex` and `lualatex`

Comment: Imho not easy. The font probably works through ligatures of the 8-bit components. Unless you have a very pressing need I would suggest to drop the idea. Btw: I think that it doesn't work correctly with pdflatex in texlive 2018 due to the active inputenc.

Comment: I searched this site but I can't find a  convincing method for using traditional tfm font with specific encoding   in xelatex

Comment: What is the font in question? Is it only available in this format?

Comment: Its an arabic font from `arabi` package 
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/language/arabic/arabi/arabi/texmf/fonts

Comment: why should a "convincing method" (what probably means an easy method) exists to use with an unicode engine a font with an quite specific encoding geared toward an 8-bit engine like pdflatex? If you really want it: use fontforge to create a suitable otf from the pfb's. Expect that it will take many hours.

Comment: I think it's mentioned that you can use tfm font with xelatex in the   manual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, there’s no need to struggle with older encodings, because you can get a `.ttf` version of ae_AlYermook from the Debian package [fonts-arabeyes](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/fonts-arabeyes), and the `.sfd` FontForge source from [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/arabeyes-art/khotot/tree/master/decorative).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[novoc]{arabluatex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{AlYarmook}
\begin{document}
\txarb{الأول: في الدلالة على وجود للمبدأ الأول}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Since this is a unicode version of the font, tools such as `pdftotext` extract the correct text from the PDF.

It is indeed possible to use older fonts and encodings in documents to be compiled with xetex or luatex. But the results become less satisfactory, and the text’s accessibility worse, the more complex the script. For example, you’re unlikely to notice problems if you set a word or two in uncials from the `bookhands` package. However, Arabic script is many times more complex than uncials.